# How to add directive conditionally in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

could you please tell me how to add directive conditionally  in angular js.Actually I am generating my view from **JSON**  I want to add custom directive to **some fields only** which have checkInput property.Example I make a custom directive name **"checkInput"** I want to add this in input field which have "checkInput"  property true

```
"First Name": {
    "value": "",
    "type": "FIELD",
    "editable": true,
    "dataType": "",
     "required":true,
     "checkInput":true
  },
```

could you please tell me how I will add this

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/YmIMEGHm7E48wZQT9ZSb?p=preview

```
.directive("checkInput", function() {
  return {
 require: "ngModel",
 //name your scope key and value.

 link: function(scope, element, attributes, modelVal) {

    modelVal.$validators.checkInput= function(val) {
       var phonenoRegex = /^[0-9]+$/;
       if (val.match(phonenoRegex))
       {
      return false
       }
       else{
         return true
       }

        console.log(val);

    };

    scope.$watch("val", function() {
        modelVal.$validate();
    });

}

};
});
```

**Update**

In my example I have only first name has **"checkInput":true** property .So I want to add this directive only in **First name** .Not is all input field

any update ?

any update

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: it's named `checkInput` so you need to add `check-input` to your input field. You can check for an error with `myform[key].$error.checkInput` (it will be `true` if **invalid**, and blank if valid)

Comment: you didn't get my question.will explain more

Comment: please check my update'

Comment: I want to add. this directive only those input field which have` "checkInput":true `property

Comment: add another attribute, e.g. `validate="{{value.checkInput}}"` along with `check-input`, and collect it in your directive with `attributes.validate`

Comment: how could you please change my pluker

Comment: it will be good if you change my plunker

Comment: here, try [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/z6Njlk6orBeNXvYhXqYJ?p=preview)

Comment: a good way, Kindly guide me, i think doing this way will call directive on all three fields, and only validate one, consider there are 100 input fields in table and he only needs to validate one. directive will run on all 100 fields and will only validate one. Is it efficient or good approach? @AlekseySolovey

Comment: any use of watchers will make it slow, compilation of templates might slow it down as well. Simply reduce those if you have any, but otherwise it should be fine as longs you have less than 10000 inputs

Comment: I up voted it, I think you should make this a proper answer, so that others can benefit form it.

Comment: @ahsanayub could you please suggest better solution

Comment: @Joy check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

@Joy You want to validate only First Name. You can use this work around.

```
<div ng-if="(key=='First Name')">
    <input type="text" name="{{key}}" class="form-control" ng-model="value.value" ng-required="value.required && isSubmitClicked" check-input>
</div>
<div ng-if="(key!='First Name')">
    <input type="text" name="{{key}}" class="form-control" ng-model="value.value" ng-required="value.required && isSubmitClicked" >
</div>
```

I hope i answered your question. Accept the answer and if you have any confusion let me know. :)